# How to create a wavy lines with MetaPost?

Tags: macros, metapost

I am looking for a macro or whatever code that can draw a wavy curves with MetaPost.

In other words, I need a wavy/spring version of what follows:

```
beginfig(1);
z1 = (0,0);
z2 = (3,2);
z3 = (6,0);
draw z1 .. z2 .. z3;
endfig;
```

This would produce a curve from `z1` to `z3`. What I need is how to make this curve wavy?

What I need is a curve with spring like the following spring but being curved...

[image]

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. `:-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you should begin by specifying directions to follow at the nodes of your path, like these for example:

```
u := 1cm;
beginfig(1);
z1 = (0,0);
z2 = (3,2)*u;
z3 = (6,0)*u;
for i=1,2,3: draw z[i] withpen pencircle scaled 3bp; endfor;
draw z1{up} .. z2{dir -45} .. z3{dir 45};
setbounds currentpicture to boundingbox currentpicture enlarged 10bp;
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

Once it suits your needs, you may put it in a macro.

**UPDATE** the metaobj package may be what you need. See [its documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/metaobj).

```
input metaobj;
u := 1cm;
beginfig(1);
z1 = (0,0);
z2 = (3,2)*u;
z3 = (6,0)*u;
nczigzag(z1)(z2), "angleA(90)", "angleB(-45)", "arrows(-)", "coilwidth(0.2u)",
    "coilarmA(0)", "coilarmB(0)";
nczigzag(z2)(z3), "angleA(-45)", "angleB(45)", "arrows(-)", "coilwidth(0.2u)",
    "coilarmA(0)", "coilarmB(0)";
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

Comment: Probably `nczigzag(z1)(z2), "angleA(90)", "angleB(0)", "arrows(-)", "coilwidth(0.2u)", "coilarmA(0)", "coilarmB(0)";` and `nczigzag(z2)(z3), "angleA(0)", "angleB(-90)", "arrows(-)", "coilwidth(0.2u)", "coilarmA(0)", "coilarmB(0)";` looks closer to the OP's path.

Comment: @karlkoeller: you're right at least for the "coilarms", this is now fixed. Not sure for the directions, though.

Comment: I don't know, either. But the OP's picture is just an arc.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't feel up to learning the whole of [MetaObj](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/metaobj) just to do zig-zags or wiggles then you might like these two functions, based on the `arctime` command.  They draw "wiggles" or "zig-zags" along more or less any path.  I've tried to keep them simple, but they are far from perfect, so any suggested improvements would be welcome.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

% Be reasonable with these lengths.  If you use `drawarrow` then 
% you should ensure that s_lambda > ahlength

s_lambda = 6; % the length of the waves
s_angle = 45; % the angle of attack 

vardef sinuous expr p = 
   save ut; hide( ut := arctime s_lambda of p;) 
   point 0 of p {curl 0} ..
      for i=1 step 2 until floor(length p / ut)-2:
            point     i*ut of p { (direction     i*ut of p) rotated +s_angle } ..
            point (i+1)*ut of p { (direction (i+1)*ut of p) rotated -s_angle } ..
          endfor
          { direction length p of p } point length p of p
   enddef;

z_lambda = 6; % the length of the zig-zags
z_amp   = 2.4; % the amplitude of each zig and zag

vardef ziggy expr p = 
   save ut; hide( ut := arctime z_lambda of p;) 
   point 0 of p { direction 0 of p } ..
      for i=2 step 2 until floor(length p / ut)-3:
            point     i*ut of p + z_amp*up   rotated angle direction     i*ut of p --
            point (i+1)*ut of p + z_amp*down rotated angle direction (i+1)*ut of p --
          endfor
          point length p - ut of p -- point length p of p
   enddef;

% example of usage
beginfig(1);
  path p ;
  p := origin {dir 60} .. {down} (210,20);
  drawarrow sinuous p shifted 20up withcolor red;
  drawarrow ziggy   p shifted 10up withcolor blue;
  drawarrow p; 
endfig;
end.
```

[image]

The OP diagram could be done something like this:

```
beginfig(2);
  z1 = (0,0);
  z2 = (3cm,2cm);
  z3 = (6cm,0);
  z_amp := 1mm;
  z_lambda := .8mm;
  draw ziggy z1 .. z2 .. z3;
  fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted z1;
  fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted z3;
endfig;
```

[image]